# PHP Regular Expression to quotations to attributes

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I need to run a string of html through a regex function that checks to see if the attributes are closed in quotes, and if they aren't then close them.

for example i want

```
<img src=http://www.domain.com/image.gif border=0>
```

to turn into

```
<img src='http://www.domain.com/image.gif' border='0'>
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using Tidy? Regexp really isn't the way to go around HTML.

Comment: I really only need to enclose the SRC='' attribute. So regex will be good for this I believe. It doesn't have to work perfectly on a large scale, just work perfectly for <img src=> situations

Comment: Well (at your own peril): `preg_replace("/=([^'" ]+)/", "=\"$1\"", $html)`. It's pretty simple but should do the job in simple and standard cases.

Comment: Thanks for your help, in my test case that yields :


<IMG SRC="06032102.jpg WIDTH=250 HEIGHT=200 BORDER=0 ALIGN=left>"


Can you help me refine the code?

Comment: A forgot to escape and the end angled bracket: `preg_replace("/=([^'\"> ]+)/", "=\"$1\"", $html)`. This works on my php.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to parse, or validate, HTML is a complex job best not attempted with a regex. There are just too many possibilities for it to be efficient.

Jakub got there before me, but I agree. Use tools that exist for the job like HTML Tidy - http://tidy.sourceforge.net/

It can fix invalid HTML, see a nice overview at http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/

There is some PHP integration at https://www.php.net/tidy